# Extrapolate two columns from txt with commas and text

Tags: octave

I got a problem reading some data from a txt file. I appreciate any suggestion and thank you in advance!

I have a txt file with text/number on top, followed by two tab-separated columns (additionally, they have commas instead of dots).

I want to extract the two columns without text, and replace the commas with dots in order to plot them.

I tried with `importdata` to be able to replace the commas, but it separates every single character, so I get 36k elements instead of 2048.
Tried `dlmread` but it ignores the second column...

I have no idea how to proceed without modifying every single file manually.

here is an example of the file:

```
Data from FLMS012901__118__10-30-26-589.txt Node

Date: Tue Jul 05 10:30:26 CEST 2022
User: Myself
Number of Pixels in Spectrum: 2048
>>>>>Begin Spectral Data<<<<<
338,147 -2183,94
338,527 -2183,94
338,906 -2183,94
339,286 -2251,25
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
Apparently, there was already a solution, even though a bit slow:

```
    % Read file in as a series of strings
fid = fopen('data.txt', 'rb');
strings = textscan(fid, '%s', 'Delimiter', '');
fclose(fid);

% Replace all commas with decimal points
decimal_strings = regexprep(strings{1}, ',', '.');

% Convert to doubles and join all rows together
data = cellfun(@str2num, decimal_strings, 'uni', 0);
data = cat(1, data{:});
```

Answer (score 0):

On the sample that you provide, the following works:

```
>> [a,b,c,d] = textread("SO_73502149.txt","%f,%f %f,%f", "headerlines", 6); 
>> format free
>> [a+b/1000, c+sign(c).*d/100]
ans =
 338.147 -2183.94
 338.527 -2183.94
 338.906 -2183.94
 339.286 -2251.25
```

However there are some possible traps, according to the way decimal figures are handled in your file, you should adapt the post-processing: If for 338.10 338,1 is printed in the file instead of 338,10 , the decoding would be a bit harder. Whenever `c` becomes zero, sign(c) would kill the decimal part. A less trivial post-processing would be required.